# Find location of GRUB2/Multiboot 'module' (aka initrd)

Tags: osdev, grub2, initrd, multiboot

I am working on an OS, and need to load an INITRD (grub command "module") and can't find info on where (in RAM) the module is loaded to

Does grub have a way of telling me or is it a fixed address or none of the above?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The vote to close indicates a misunderstanding of the question. This question is about programming, and would be off-topic on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

This information is passed to the OS as part of the [multiboot information structure](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#Boot-information-format) data.

Although if you're working on a new OS, you may want to follow the (incompatible) [Multiboot2 specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot2/multiboot.html#Modules) (using grub commands multiboot2/module2) instead.